# How can I get the active number of threads for the current step in an active thread group?

Tags: jmeter

Trying to get the current number of threads in my thread group when using a "dynamic" thread group (like Stepping/Ultimate thead group etc).

I tried a JSR223preprocessor with

`vars.putObject('allthreads', prev.getAllThreads())`

which sort of works but, as expected, when using `prev.getAllThreads()` I get the number for the previous "step" (and for the first step it's empty). Is it any way I can get it for the current "step"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would rather go for `ctx` class instance which stands for [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html):

- `ctx.getThreadGroup().getNumThreads()` - returns the number of threads you (or whoever else) defined in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) (or its derivative)
- `ctx.getThreadGroup().getNumberOfThreads()` - returns number of threads which are currently active

There is also [JMeterContextService](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContextService.html) class which provides [`getThreadCounts()`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContextService.html#getThreadCounts--) function which might be easier to use.

More information: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)